# My menu is still open

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I try to make navigation menu in hamburger style...I made html, css and JS and everything is ok, but when I click link in menu, so menu doesn't hide and still is open. **I need to hide menu when I click on link link**
Really don't have idea why it doesn't work because for example toggle on cross is ok.

Here is CODE. HTML + JS are together:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800');

body {
  background: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  color: #EBEBD3;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.logo span {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.site-nav {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.site-nav--open {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 100;
}

.site-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.site-nav li {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;*/
}

.site-nav li:last-child {
  /* border-bottom: none; */
}

.site-nav a {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus {
  color: white;
}

.menu-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .75em;
  top: .75em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: #ebebbd;
  height: 3px;
  width: 1.75em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger::before {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.open .hamburger::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(90deg);
}

.open .hamburger {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#particles-js {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

#about {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}

#portfolio {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

#contact {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Doplniť neskôr">
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="logo">Try <span>it</span></h1>
      <nav class="site-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#particles-js">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <div class="hamburger"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <div id="about"></div>
  <div id="portfolio"></div>
  <div id="contact"></div>

  <script src="js/particles.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
      $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 500);
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you !

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800');

body {
  background: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 
}

.container {
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
header {

  color: #EBEBD3;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: fixed;
 width: 100%
}
header::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.logo span {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.site-nav {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #1d1d1d;
 top: 100%;
 right: 0;
 height: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 0;
 width: 100%;
 
}
.site-nav--open {
 height: auto;
 opacity: 100;
}
.site-nav ul {
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
}
.site-nav li {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
/* border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;*/
}
.site-nav li:last-child {
/* border-bottom: none; */
}
.site-nav a {
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #9E9E9E;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 2em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus {
 
 color: white;
}
.menu-toggle {
 position: fixed;
 padding: 1em;
 position: absolute;
 right: .75em;
 top: .75em;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 background-color: #ebebbd;
 height: 3px;
 width: 1.75em;
 border-radius: 3px;
 transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger::before {
 
 transform: translateY(-6px);
}
.hamburger::after {
 transform: translateY(3px);
 
}


.open .hamburger::before {
 opacity: 0;
}
.open .hamburger::after{
 transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(90deg);
 
}
.open .hamburger {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#particles-js {
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: #1d1d1d;
}
#about {
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: green;
 
}
#portfolio {
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: blue;
 
}
#contact {
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Doplniť neskôr">
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <body>
        <header>
         <div class="container">
          <h1 class="logo">Try <span>it</span></h1>
          <nav class="site-nav">
           <ul>
            <li><a class="menu-link" href="#particles-js">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
          </nav>
          <div class="menu-toggle">
           <div class="hamburger"></div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </header>
        <div id="particles-js"></div>
        <div id="about"></div>
        <div id="portfolio"></div>
        <div id="contact"></div>

<script src="js/particles.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script>  
    
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
  
  $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 500);
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
  
});
$('.menu-link').click(function(){
 $('.site-nav').toggleClass('close site-nav--open');
 $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('open')
});

  </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added new function which closes menu on `.menu-link` click.

I believe it solves your problem.

#### Snippet

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800');

body {
  background: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  color: #EBEBD3;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.logo span {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.site-nav {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.site-nav--open {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 100;
}

.site-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.site-nav li {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;*/
}

.site-nav li:last-child {
  /* border-bottom: none; */
}

.site-nav a {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus {
  color: white;
}

.menu-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .75em;
  top: .75em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: #ebebbd;
  height: 3px;
  width: 1.75em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger::before {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.open .hamburger::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(90deg);
}

.open .hamburger {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#particles-js {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

#about {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}

#portfolio {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

#contact {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Doplniť neskôr">
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="logo">Try <span>it</span></h1>
      <nav class="site-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="menu-link" href="#particles-js">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <div class="hamburger"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <div id="about"></div>
  <div id="portfolio"></div>
  <div id="contact"></div>

  <script src="js/particles.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
      $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 500);
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    })
    $('.menu-link').click(function() {
      $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 500);
      $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('open');
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```